# when bottom of ".hiddenpost" is at top of screen toggle it

Tags: jquery, html

I never had to ask and always found the right answer myself but today I´ll have to ask here cause I didn't find the right answer (even with the advanced search).

So to my problem: I want toggle an element if the top of the screen reaches the bottom of that element (with jQuery of course). The thing is my function does not work and I do not know how to solve this, I really searched for a long time on the internet but could not find anything unfortunately.

Could you please help me?
I used to toggle it like that:

```
$(".tablee").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

jQuery (my try to toggle if element´s bottom reached screen´s top):

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("scroll",function(){
      $(".hiddenpost").each(function(){
        var x = $(this);
        if ((x.offset().bottom + x.height()) <= $(window).height()) {
          x.slideToggle();
        }
      });
   });
});
```

HTML (reduced to the important things):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tablee" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="hiddenpost"  style="height:400px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tablee" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="hiddenpost"  style="height:400px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tablee" style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="hiddenpost"  style="height:400px;"></div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: if you require more information please let me know!

Comment: `x.offset()` does not return any `bottom` property. There is only `top` and `left`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $(function(){
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(".hiddenpost").each(function(){
                var divBottomPosition = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                if (divBottomPosition < scrollPosition) $(this).slideToggle();
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!